# compare two columns from one excel sheet with other 2 columns in other sheet and highlight the differences

Tags: excel, vba, macos

Let me be more specific and clear about the question. All i want to do is ...
I want to compare for example say, column 1 (C1) is fruits. column 2 (C2) is quantity.

**Sheet1 :**

```
  C1       C2  

Orange     324

Apple      108

Grape      24

Mango      30
```

**Sheet2:**

```
C1        C2 

Apple      40   

Grape      90

Peach      24
```

Now, The two sheets needed to be compared, All the fruits which are present in sheet1 but not in sheet2 should be colored in red and all the fruits which are present in sheet2 but not in sheet1 should be colored in red.
And,
keeping sheet1 as constant, 
sheet 2 is compared with sheet1, and if apples are present in sheet1 then, if apples in sheet2 are lesser than sheet1 then the quantity should be colored in yellow. 
If the quantity in sheet2 is greater than sheet 1 then the quantity should be colored in  green. so on.. for all the fruits(column1) and quantity(column2) in sheet2 with all the fruits(column1) and quantity(column2) in sheet1.

Please help me. Thank you.

This is the code I have tried..

```
Sub checkrev2()  

With Sheets("Sheet1")  
Sh1LastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row  
Set Sh1Range = .Range("E9:F" & Sh1LastRow)  
Set num1Range = .Range("F9:F" & Sh1LastRow)  
End With  
With Sheets("Sheet2")  
Sh2LastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row  
Set Sh2Range = .Range("G14:H" & Sh2LastRow)  
Set num2Range = .Range("H14:H" & Sh2LastRow)  
End With  

'compare sheet 1 with sheet 2  
For Each Sh1Cell In Sh1Range  
Set c = Sh2Range.Find( _  
what:=Sh1Cell, LookIn:=xlValues)  
If c Is Nothing Then  
Sh1Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3  
Sh1Cell.Offset(0, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 3  
Else  
If Sh1Cell.Offset(1, 0) > c.Offset(1, 0) Then  
Sh1Cell.Offset(0, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 0  
End If  
End If  
Next Sh1Cell  

For Each Sh2Cell In Sh2Range  
Set f = Sh1Range.Find( _  
what:=Sh2Cell, LookIn:=xlValues)  
If f Is Nothing Then  
Sh2Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3  
Sh2Cell.Offset(0, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 3  
Else  
If c.Offset(1, 0) = f.Offset(1, 0) Then  
c.Offset(0, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 8  
End If  
End If  
Next Sh2Cell  
End Sub
```

With this code I am able to do the first part of the question... that is, comparing the columns in sheet1 with columns in sheet2 and highlighting the differences in RED color.

Comment: Is there anything you have tried so far? Any bit of code you tried working with?

Comment: For Each Sh1Cell In Sh1Range
Set c = Sh2Range.Find( _
what:=Sh1Cell, LookIn:=xlValues)
If c Is Nothing Then
Sh1Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
Sh1Cell.Offset(0, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
Else
If Sh1Cell.Offset(0, 1) <> c.Offset(0, 1) Then
Sh1Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
Sh1Cell.Offset(0, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 8
End If
End If
Next Sh1Cell

Comment: Please, edit your question and put the code into it. In a comment, it is unreadable.